# A good way to show a sub dialog and making it thread safe

Tags: android, thread-safety

I have a function to display some selectable items in a dialog.
It looks like this:

```
void showListDialog()
{
if (!_dialogIsOpen) {
    _dialogIsOpen = true;
    final Activity instance = this;

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {   
            //Building the List to display

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() 
            {                       
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    _dialogIsOpen = false;                          
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Now I want to make the call thread safe.
For now you can see that I use a check on a boolean field with the name "_dialogIsOpen". The access on that field is not synchronized!

My question is what do I have to change to make this function thread safe. And if the use of the "runnable" in the UiThread is a good idea for showing a sub dialog on the ui.

Comment: you can you check for dialog as dialog.isShowing();

Comment: Hm I changed my code that I have a class reference to my dialog. Before the call I check if it's already visible. I think it's a good way to solve the task